# How to change font or size of text before printing using PrintService

Tags: java, printing

So the question is pretty straight forward. I have this method:

```
public void printString(String printerName, String text) {

DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
        flavor, pras);
PrintService service = findPrintService(printerName, printService);
DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

try {
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes = text.getBytes("CP437");
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
    job.print(doc, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and I want to change font and size of text before printing.
I was playing around with PrintRequestAttributeSet but it doesn't seem like I can change the font or the size of text to be printed in this. Is it even possible to change font and size? I tried [Java Printing Font Stretch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352243/java-printing-font-stretch) but It doesn't seem to do anything when I set the resolution. What can I do about it?

Additional info: I'm using RP58E POS Thermal printer